# How can I ask the user to select the app he wants to use to open a file?

Tags: android, android-intent, file-manager

I'm trying to make my own file manager for android.
I am wondering how I could asks the user to choose the application he wants to use open a file. like when you are opening a .doc file and you have a bunch of .doc file readers. How would I be able to retrieve the list of apps that the user can use to read/open a file?

[image: Here's a screenshot.]

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("Your file name: //"+file.getAbsolutePath());
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
String type = "application/msword";
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), type);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use implicit intent for your purpose. Below is the sample code for giving options to play a video file

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("https://youtu.be/jxoG_Y6dvU8"), "video/*");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"));
```

I hope it will help you out. For further details you may refer android official documentation as mentioned in below link

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html#AppChooser

Comment: When I click a png file. it does not show gallery from the list of apps. How do I like make it if the file type is png, the list of apps is for opening images. and when it is .doc it shows document readers? sorry. i really am bad at programming.
EDIT: oh, i think it's the setDataAndType code. lol. i'm going to try it

Comment: hmm try and let me know if you found any problem

Comment: I ussed this code `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        String title = getResources().getString(R.string.chooser_title);
        intent.setType("*/*");
        Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, title);` 
It shows a different a bunch of apps. that's all I can do. I'm not sure how to make it show only gallery apps for images and file readers for .doc and .pdf files. i'm so dumb haha

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this

```
Intent in= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
in.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.package.address","com.package.address.MainActivity"));
startActivity(in);
```